# Angular 1.0.8: How to skip an iteration in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to skip an iteration in ng-repeat without manipulating the underlying array/object that it iterates over?

Say we have this:

```
var steps = [
    {
        enabled: true
    },
    {
        enabled: true
    },
    {
        enabled: false
    }
];
```

And I want to skip the third step by looking at its "enabled" key.
In more modern angular I would use:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="step in steps" data-ng-if="step.enabled">
```

However `ng-if` does not exist in 1.0.8.

I tried creating a filter like so:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="step in steps | isEnabled" data-ng-if="step.enabled">
```

JS:

```
filter('isEnabled', function() {
    return function(input) {

        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if(!input[i]['enabled']) {
                input.splice(i, 1);
            }
        };

        return input;
    };
})
```

But that manipulates the original step object which cannot happen.
I then tried to clone the steps:

```
filter('isEnabled', function() {
    return function(input) {

        var stepsBackup = angular.copy(input);

        for(var i = 0; i < stepsBackup.length; i++) {
            if(!stepsBackup[i]['enabled']) {
                stepsBackup.splice(i, 1);
            }
        };

        return stepsBackup;
    };
})
```

But that just throws errors: `Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to define a custom filter. AngularJS filters support filtering on properties if you pass in an object as the `filter:` expression. For instance:

```
<li ng-repeat="step in steps | filter: {enabled: true}">...</li>
```

Check out this fiddle, which I think demonstrates what you're after (it uses Angular 1.0.8):

http://jsfiddle.net/ck9u6/